# WPF combobox not showing suggestion like winform combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling with WPF Combobox in order to show suggestion while user is typing like this (in WinForms):

[image]

But what is happing is that the combobox is appending when user is typing like this (in WPF):

[image]

**Problem**
How can I show a dropdown list when user is typing as suggestions

Many many thanks for your attention.

**My Code:**

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="item_category" Width="190" IsEditable="True" SelectionChanged="category_SelectionChanged"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this event to your `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Name="cmb1" IsEditable="True" PreviewTextInput="cmb1_PreviewTextInput">
</ComboBox>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
List<string> db;
public Window()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     db = new List<string> { "abc","abg","hjn" };
     cmb1.ItemsSource = db;
}

private void cmb1_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
     cmb1.ItemsSource = db.Where(p => p.Contains(e.Text)).ToList();
     cmb1.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: @VikasBansal ... `db` is a source that your `ComboBox` is populated from.

Comment: @user2946329 my datasource is a datatable and i am converting to defaultview in order bind it. now, I am doing it like this:  categories.DefaultView.Where(p => p.Field.Contains(e.Text)).ToList(); but it is not working

Comment: @VikasBansal ... Please now check my updated answer. It is a complete example that should works fine for you. Then you can change the datasource as your need.

Comment: I have created a dummy and its working great. But what when I am typing lts missing some words like when I typed 123456789, some letters were missed. Sometimes I have to type a number twice. Just do not know why it is happening. P.S: I have binded combbox with database "over 1000 number")

Comment: @VikasBansal ... For numbers you can use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`AutoCompleteBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.autocompletebox(v=vs.95).aspx) which behaves dropdown as well as autocomplete.

You can install from this [version](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)

Comment: it is a part of silverlight. Will I be able to use it in WPF?

Comment: Yes you can, there are lot of examples

Comment: I have downloaded the toolkit. Now @Sajeetharan how can I add AutoCompleteBox directly in XML. Also, will I be able to bind data and value members? may thanks :)